# Adding secondary DNS

Tags: dns, cloudflare, ovh

In my company we rely on the services provided by OVH, including the DNS provided by it.
Having had some disservices in recent times there is the need to change DNS provider or add secondary DNS from other providers.
In my small experience I thought of staying on OVH as the primary DNS and adding secondary DNS on CloudFlare, but I don't know if that would be the best strategy.
Do you have any suggestions or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

- of course possible, you only need to allow the slave servers to get updates e.g. via AXFR
- OVH offers secondary DNS for non-OVH domains , if they do not provide (external) secondary Settings , you would have to change the registrar
- [(older) forum Post on OVH secondary NS](https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/how-to-set-ovh-secondary-dns.53883/)
- [(older) blog post with some providers](https://bornoe.org/blog/2015/10/free-secondary-slave-dns/)
- you should go for hurricane electric or cloudns ( or any other provider with geographically distributed nameservers and maybe even [Geocast](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocast)